# How to change the line a string is found on with the output of another program to which you pass that string as an argument?

Tags: linux, sed

```
$ cat sample.dmesg.log | sed -re 's/(READ block )([0-9]+)( on xvda3.*$)/\1\2\3 XXX/g'
[ 6031.953619] sysctl(20774): READ block 5285528 on xvda3 (32 sectors) XXX
[ 6031.954317] sysctl(20774): READ block 5285768 on xvda3 (8 sectors) XXX
[ 6031.954598] sysctl(20774): READ block 5285648 on xvda3 (120 sectors) XXX
[ 6031.954617] sysctl(20774): READ block 5285776 on xvda3 (24 sectors) XXX
[ 6031.955482] sysctl(20774): READ block 5285560 on xvda3 (88 sectors) XXX
[ 6031.955699] sysctl(20774): READ block 4473568 on xvda3 (8 sectors) XXX
[ 6031.955730] sysctl(20774): READ block 4473584 on xvda3 (16 sectors) XXX
[ 6031.955787] sysctl(20774): READ block 4749496 on xvda3 (224 sectors) XXX
```

For each input line, I want to replace the `XXX` above with the result of running the command `./showblock NUMBER`, where `NUMBER` is `\2` (second group) in the above `sed` eg. 5285528

But how can I find, execute a program, then replace/modify at the same time?

Sample result:

```
[ 6031.953619] sysctl(20774): READ block 5285528 on xvda3 (32 sectors) Path: /usr/lib64/libgpg-error.so.0.24.2
```

Hopefully this can this be done with the same `sed` command; or some other **one** command?

If someone knows how else to rephrase this question so that it's more generic and useful, please do so.

In other words: How to execute external program in the middle of the regex/regexp match ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try perl:

```
perl -pe '
    s{(READ block) (\d+) (on xvda3.*$)}
     {join " ",$1, $2, $3, qx(./showblock $2)}e
' sample.dmesg.log
```

To remove the trailing newline, you could do

```
     { chomp($out = qx(./showblock $2)); join " ", $1, $2, $3, $out }e
```

Comment: Impressive! Do you know if `sed` has this capability? (to execute command) I'll assume it doesn't.

Comment: @MarcusLinsner - only `gnu sed` can do that via the `e` flag...

Comment: There seems to be an implied newline added when replacing, other than the one that `./showblock` outputs. I think maybe `join` adds one ? Can I remove that? ie. I'm getting a blank line after each replaced line.

Comment: the output from `qx(...)` includes a trailing newline, and the current line already has one.

Comment: I was looking the `s` [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) to match the current line's newline(aka `\n`, aka `$`) via the `.`, so the `}e` above becomes `}es` and the `.*`(any char(including the  new line char, now) for 0 or more times) becomes `[^\$]*`(any char that's not end of line, for 0 or more times. Note: I had to escape `$` within those `[` `]` parens). Now I can allow the output of `qx(...)` to contain the new line instead.

Comment: I only now noticed(after I posted my above comment) that you edited your answer yesterday to say how to remove the trailing newline, because [I got no notification](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4986/306023) for your edit or your above `qx` comment. So it looks like the `chomp` method that you mention complicates things less than using the `s` modifier. Thank you!

Comment: [That above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467369/how-to-change-the-line-a-string-is-found-on-with-the-output-of-another-program-t/467377#comment852158_467377) also needs a `\n`, like: `s{(READ block) (\d+) (on) ([A-Za-z0-9]+) ([^\$]*)\n$}` `{join " ",$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, qx(echo "test")}es`